# MySQL: NULL vs. Empty String vs. Front-end App

Tags: php, mysql, null, string

In my first question on this forum, I learned that `MySQL` treats `NULL` and an `empty string` differently. As an `Oracle` database-centric developer, I can accept this and even see a potential use for it. But I don't see how this works in an actual application with a front-end app.

Let's say you have a php app for entering contact information. If (in the database), the person's middle name is `NULL`, that means we don't know if the person has a middle name.

If it is an `empty string`, we know the person has no middle name.

But on the web page form, can you make this distinction? I don't see how. I can't see using (and have never seen) a checkbox or option for the user to tell the app that a text field is unknown vs. empty (none).

So please enlighten me and tell me how making a distinction in the database adds value to the big picture.

Thanks.

Comment: Null exists separately from 'data'. Unless you have a check box to indicate null you can't differentiate between null-as-empty-string v.s. null-as-unknown-value

Comment: Yes, but have you ever seen this done? I have not. So why does MySQL treat them differently if there is no practical way to make use of that distinction?

Comment: because "unknown" IS different than "empty string", or "0". Consider a financial app where records may exist but their value is unknown. if you set those records' value to 0 and do "select avg(price)", those 0's will affect the actual average. if they're null, they're ignored and don't affect the average. A null middle name would be "don't know what their name is". a blank string is "they don't have a middle name at all".

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave, no, I don't think there'd be a way to communicate to the user that the field is NULL or to allow the user to specify NULL as opposed to simply blank/empty.

Since the concept of null would be an unnecessary hardship for the end user to understand, I think generally you'd try to phrase questions and prompts to put it in terms they understand and on the backend decide how that information needs to be stored and processed.